# How to read and write to a PDF file without closing it using iText

Tags: pdf, io, itext

I am using iTextSharp to manipulate a PDF document.

Currently I am reading PDF (using PDFReader and PDFStamper), write something to it and close it. Now The processes are got increased and reading of PDF document is becoming a heavy operation in my application.

I want to read the PDF only once and close it at the end. The thing is I also need the updated document on disk after each process (without closing the stream). How can we achieve something like this from itextsharp?

```
// ReadDocument()

// WriteForProcess1()
// UpdateDocumentOnDisk ()
// ViewUpdatedDoc()

// WriteForProcess2()
// UpdateDocumentOnDisk ()
// ViewUpdatedDoc()

// WriteForProcess3()
// UpdateDocumentOnDisk ()
// ViewUpdatedDoc()

// CloseDocument()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible:

If I understand you correctly you want to

1. read a base PDF and open a `PdfStamper` for it;
2. multiple times

   a) manipulate it (using the stamper) and

   b) view the current (manipulated) state of the PDF;
3. and eventually close the `PdfStamper` and write the final result file.

Unless your PDF viewer in step 2b is able to display the PDF using only the current in-memory representation of the state of stamping the PDF (I don't know any such viewer), though, step 2b already requires the stamper to be closed and the PDF completely written to the file system.

Having closed the stamper you obviously need to open a new one to continue, and this new one has to be based on a `PdfReader` initialized with the current file content.

Concerning your central issue:

> reading of PDF document is becoming a heavy operation in my application.

Depending on the way you manipulate the PDF in each iteration, it might not be necessary to parse the whole existing PDF, e.g. if you only manipulate a small set of its pages or only append new pages each time.

If this is the case, you should consider using a `PdfReader` constructor which only partially parses the PDF and copies the rest without requiring resources for parsing.

**PS:** The OP commented:

> What is in RandomAccessFileOrArray? Is this something used to read partial documents. It reduces file reading time drastically from 3 seconds to 300ms :)

Yes, the `PdfReader` constructor accepting a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` is the one working in partial mode, cf. the constructor code comment:

```
    /**
    * Reads and parses a pdf document. Contrary to the other constructors only the xref is read
    * into memory. The reader is said to be working in "partial" mode as only parts of the pdf
    * are read as needed.
    * @param raf the document location
    * @param ownerPassword the password or <CODE>null</CODE> for no password
    * @throws IOException on error
    */
```

Comment: Also: why does the OP need the document *on disk* after each operation? Keeping it in memory would make more sense from a *general* point of view (but of course: we don't know the exact use case).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *Also: why does the OP need the document on disk after each operation?* - I assume his PDF viewer requires an on-disc representation of the file.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am using AcroPDFLib to load the PDF file which supports only file path to load the document.

Comment: What is in RandomAccessFileOrArray? Is this something used to read partial documents. It reduces file reading time drastically from 3 seconds to 300ms :) @mkl

Comment: That's exactly how to employ *partial* mode.